Trying to make a dynamic horizontal navigation bar where nav items "overflow" into a "more" dropdown when those nav items would normally wrap
I'm trying to make a vanilla javascript driven dynamic horizontal navigation bar where the individual nav items "overflow" into and out of a "more" dropdown nav item when those trailing nav items would normally wrap to a second line (depending on the viewport width).
Imagine a horizontal nav made up of the following 6 individual nav items:

nav item 1 |
nav item 2 |
some other nav item 3 |
another nav item 4 |
nav item 5 |
another nav item with a longer name 6

On wide displays, the nav displays just like it does above because there is enough horizontal room to display all nav items without wrapping to a second line.
When the browser width is reduced, the nav may display like so (where nav items 5 & 6) are now in a "more" dropdown nav item that appears:

nav item 1 |
nav item 2 |
some other nav item 3 |
another nav item 4 |
more ▾

When that width is reduced even further, the nav may display like so (where nav items 4, 5 & 6) are now in a "more" dropdown nav item:

nav item 1 |
nav item 2 |
some other nav item 3 |
more ▾

When the browser width is increased, it works in the opposite way, nav items are "removed" from the more dropdown menu and "added" back to the main nav.
The nav items would be dynamic, the text is not known nor is the number of nav items, though there wouldn't be an excessive amount.
I have a prototype which is kind of working, but is not working as I'd hoped: https://jsfiddle.net/fr2ug76p/
The nav is beneath the hero and becomes fixed as you scroll down the page.
You'll probably notice a semi-transparent "more" at the end of the nav. That is always there in the nav and it has some padding on the right.  This basically serves as the trigger to start the overflowing of nav items into the "more" dropdown. If you size your browser width down, you'll see the "more" become fully opaque when the overflow starts, so the semi-transparent "more" is more of a visual cue that it's always there.
The nav is repeated 2x, once for the horizontal display, once for the "more" dropdown.  I just show and hide the individual nav items appropriately.
There is also some text and dimensions output I was using for development and debugging.
There is also some debouncing on the window resize which drives everything a little more efficiently.
How would you make this much more smoother and fluid in regards to the display of nav items in and out of the more dropdown depending on the viewport width?
Here again is the prototype url: https://jsfiddle.net/fr2ug76p/
Here is the prototype html:
<header><p>fixed header</p></header>
        
<main>
  <div class="hero"><p>hero</p></div>

  <nav class="subnav">
    <ul class="subnav-list">
      <li class="nav1"><a href="#1">nav item 1</a></li>
      <li class="nav2"><a href="#2">nav item 2</a></li>
      <li class="nav3"><a href="#3">some other nav item 3</a></li>
      <li class="nav4"><a href="#4">another nav item 4</a></li>
      <li class="nav5"><a href="#5">nav item 5</a></li>
      <li class="nav6"><a href="#6">another nav item with a longer name 6</a></li>
      <li class="more">
        <a href="#more" class="more-link" style="display:inline-block; border:1px dashed blue;">more &#9660;</a>
        <ul class="subnav-dropdown no-display">
          <li class="nav1 no-display"><a href="#1">nav item 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav2 no-display"><a href="#2">nav item 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav3 no-display"><a href="#3">some other nav item 3</a></li>
          <li class="nav4 no-display"><a href="#4">another nav item 4</a></li>
          <li class="nav5 no-display"><a href="#5">nav item 5</a></li>
          <li class="nav6 no-display"><a href="#6">another nav item with a longer name 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <p>
    <span style="background:#efefef; padding:0 4px;">subnav width:</span> <span class="subnav-width"></span><br>
    subnav left/right padding: <span class="subnav-padding"></span><br><br>

    <span style="border:1px solid red;">nav list width:</span> <span class="subnav-nav-list-width"></span><br>
    nav item widths: <span class="nav-item-widths"></span><br>
    nav item widths total: <span class="nav-item-widths-total"></span><br>
    more width: <span class="more-width"></span>
  </p>
</main>

Here is the prototype css:
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

body {
  background: #ccc;
}

header {
  background: #fff;
  height:100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
  z-index: 10;
}

header,
.hero {
  display: flex;
}

header p,
.hero p {
  margin: auto;
}

.hero {
  background: #999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

main {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: #fff;
  height: 2000px;
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin: 100px auto 2rem auto;
}

.subnav {
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px;
}

.subnav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.subnav > ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.subnav ul li {
  padding: 0 .5em;
}

.subnav > ul > li:first-of-type {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.subnav > ul > li:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.subnav ul li.more {
  position: relative;
}

.subnav ul li.more .subnav-dropdown {
  display: block;
  padding: .5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem; 
  width: 160px;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);*/
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav ul li.more .subnav-dropdown li {
  padding: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
}

.subnav ul li.more .subnav-dropdown li:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.no-display {
  display: none !important;
}

Here is the prototype javascript:
//elems
const subnav = document.querySelector('.subnav');
const mainNav = subnav.querySelector('.subnav-list');
const moreNav = subnav.querySelector('.subnav-dropdown');
const moreLink = subnav.querySelector('.more > a');
const moreLinkPadding = 50;

moreLink.style.paddingRight = moreLinkPadding + 'px';

//elem dimensions
let subnavParentWidth;
let subnavNavListWidth;
let subnavParentPaddingLeft = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(subnav, null).getPropertyValue('padding-left'));
let subnavParentPaddingRight = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(subnav, null).getPropertyValue('padding-left'));
let overallChildrenNavWidth;
let moreWidth = subnav.querySelector('ul > .more').offsetWidth;
let navItemWidthsTotal = 0;

//text output in UI
const subnavWidthOutput = document.querySelector('.subnav-width');
const subnavNavListWidthOutput = document.querySelector('.subnav-nav-list-width');
const subnavPaddingOutput = document.querySelector('.subnav-padding');
const navItemWidthsOutput = document.querySelector('.nav-item-widths');
const navItemWidthsTotalOutput = document.querySelector('.nav-item-widths-total');
const moreWidthOutput = document.querySelector('.more-width');

//holds info about overflowed nav items
const more = [];

//get widths of each nav item
let getNavItemsWidth = () => {
  let total = 0;

  navItemWidthsOutput.innerHTML = '';

  let navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.subnav > ul > li');
  navItems = [...navItems].filter(navItem => !navItem.classList.contains('more'));
  navItems.forEach((navItem, index) => {
    navItem.dataset.width = navItem.offsetWidth;

    navItemWidthsOutput.innerHTML += `(${++index}) ${navItem.offsetWidth}px &nbsp;&nbsp;`;
    total += navItem.offsetWidth;
  });

  return total;
}

//output static widths in UI
navItemWidthsTotalOutput.innerText = getNavItemsWidth() + 'px';
subnavPaddingOutput.innerText = subnavParentPaddingLeft + 'px /' + subnavParentPaddingRight + 'px';
moreWidthOutput.innerText = moreWidth + 'px';

//more dropdown
moreLink.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('no-display');
});

//move trailing nav items into/out of more dropdown
let moveTrailingNavItemsIntoMore = () => {
  const difference = subnavParentWidth - overallChildrenNavWidth;

  console.log(
    'subnav parent width:', subnavParentWidth,
    '| overall children nav width:', overallChildrenNavWidth,
    '| difference:', difference
  );

  //overflow whatever last main nav item is into more dropdown
  if (difference <= 0) {
    const navItem = getPenultimateNavItem();

    more.push({
      class: navItem.classList.toString(),
      width: navItem.dataset.width
    });
  }

  console.log('subnavParentWidth - overallChildrenNavWidth:', subnavParentWidth - overallChildrenNavWidth);
  if ((subnavParentWidth - overallChildrenNavWidth) > more[more.length - 1]?.width) {
    console.log('enough room to add overflow nav item back to main nav');
    const navItem = more.pop();

    mainNav.querySelector('.' + navItem.class).classList.remove('no-display');
    moreNav.querySelector('.' + navItem.class).classList.add('no-display');
  }
  console.log('more:', more);

  if (more.length) {
    more.forEach(navItem => {
      mainNav.querySelector('.' + navItem.class).classList.add('no-display');
      moreLink.style.opacity = 1;
      //moreNav.classList.remove('no-display');
      moreNav.querySelector('.' + navItem.class).classList.remove('no-display');
    });
  } else {
    moreLink.style.opacity = .25;
    moreNav.classList.add('no-display');
  }
}

let getPenultimateNavItem = () => {
  return subnav.querySelector('ul > li:nth-last-child(1 of :not(.no-display):not(.more)');
}

//close open dropdown if clicking outside it
document.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
  if (moreNav.classList.contains('no-display')) {
    //console.log(target, 'dropdown closed do nothing');
    return;
  }

  if (target.classList.contains('more-link')) {
    //console.log(target, 'dropdown open, "more" subnav link click');
  } else if (!target.closest('ul')?.classList.contains('subnav-dropdown')) {
    //console.log(target, 'dropdown open, click outside dropdown');
    moreNav.classList.add('no-display');
  }
});

//debounce setup
let overflowIntoMoreNav = () => {
  console.log('DEBOUNCED overflowIntoMoreNav()');

  subnavParentWidth = subnav.offsetWidth;
  subnavNavListWidth = subnav.querySelector('.subnav-list').offsetWidth;
  overallChildrenNavWidth = (getNavItemsWidth() + moreWidth + subnavParentPaddingLeft + subnavParentPaddingRight);

  subnavWidthOutput.innerHTML = '<span style="background:yellow; padding:0 4px;">' + subnavParentWidth + 'px</span>';
  subnavNavListWidthOutput.innerHTML = '<span style="background:yellow; padding:0 4px;">' + subnavNavListWidth + 'px</span>';

  moveTrailingNavItemsIntoMore();
}

let debounce = (callback, delay) => {
  let myTimeout;

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
    myTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      callback()
    }, delay);
  };
};

let doDebounce = debounce(() => overflowIntoMoreNav(), 50);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => doDebounce());
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

